# Как словить момент, когда диалог Preference уже создан?

Tags: android

Мне нужно это для того чтобы изменить фоновый цвет диалога, но сделать это я не могу. т.к. при выполнении метода getDialog() вылетает nullPointer. Перепробовал такие методы как onBindView(), onBindDialogView(), onPrepareDialogBuilder(),

Answer (score 0):

Ну смотри, твой диалог скорее всего унаследован от Fragment, а значит в onCreateView() тебе ничего не мешает инфлейтить любой свой лейаут как на обычном фрагменте - это раз. Если тебе нужно переопределить только бэкграунд и есчё чего по мелочи, то можно использовать setStyle(int style, int theme).

Comment: Диfлог-то сам возможно и наследуется от класса Fragment, но класс в котором мне всё нужно выполнить наследуется от DialogPreferecne, а тот в свою очередь от класса Preference. И адекватного способа, как словить момент, когда диалог создан, я пока не нашёл